# How do I prevent Grails for doing any further validations if one validation already fails?

Tags: validation, grails

I have a Grails command object that I'm using for updating passwords. It looks like this:

```
class UpdatePasswordCommand {

    String password

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false,
                 nullable: false,
                 size: 8..64,
                 matches: someLongRegex
                 validator: { String password, command ->
                     if (someService.isPasswordSameAsUsername(password)) {
                         return 'password.invalid.sameasuser'
                     }
    }
```

I left out everything that doesn't pertain to the question I'm asking.

The problem I'm running into is that, whenever this validation triggers, it will trigger ALL the validations, and the `command.errors` collection will have an error message for each validation failure. This means that, for example, if the user tried to use **test** for the password, they will get the following error messages:

```
* Password length must be between 8 and 64 characters.
* Password must not be the same as the user name.
* Password must contain at least one special character, uppercase letter, and digit.
```

In this case, if the password length is wrong, I want the validation to stop at that point. Likewise, if it's the same as the username, I don't want it to check against the regex. Is there any way I can get the Grails validation to only return the **first** validation failure for a particular property? Note that it's important that I only want it to stop **per property**, because if the user doesn't type in his confirm password, for example, I still want to display two error messages:

```
* Password length must be between 8 and 64 characters.
* You must enter a confirm password.
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be a practice to provide all the validation messages preemptively to the user so that User can rectify or take care of them in one go, instead of rectifying it one by one?

But anyways you can programmatically force to return back only one message at a time something like below:

```
    static constraints = {
        password validator: { String password, command ->
                    def errorMsgs = []
                    if (!password){
                        errorMsgs << 'password.invalid.blank' //'password.invalid.null'
                        return errorMsgs
                    } else if (!(password.size() in (8..64))){
                        if (someService.isPasswordSameAsUsername(password)){
                            errorMsgs << 'password.invalid.sameasuser'
                        }
                        errorMsgs << 'password.invalid.length'
                        return errorMsgs
                    } else if (/*password not matching YourRegex*/){
                        errorMsgs << 'password.invalid.specialCharacters'
                        return errorMsgs
                    } else if (someService.isPasswordSameAsUsername(password)){
                        errorMsgs << 'password.invalid.sameasuser'
                        return errorMsgs
                    }
            }
    }
```

I think we have to take care of the special cases where more than one message is sent back by adding control logic as done above for password length and its match with user name.

Comment: It makes sense to return validation messages for every property, but not multiple messages for a single property. In my case, I have an old password, new password, and new pass confirm field. If I put in 'abc' for these three fields, I was getting an error for every field that told me that my password was too short, did not pass regex, and did not pass custom validation. Times that by 3 and it's 9 messages, way too excessive.

Comment: You only have one member `password` in the command object. How is old, new & confirm handled? Are you doing an XHR when each input is provided?

Comment: I put in my question, "I left out everything that doesn't pertain to the question I'm asking." The other properties are there, I just didn't include them in the example since they have nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at grails [validate](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html), the interesting thing is that you can pass property names to `validate()`. 
The second thing is [errors](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html) property that implements spring [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) interface. You can use it to clean up messages to show only one for property. 
Write a custom validator as dmahapatro suggested is a good approach.